# Lombok annotation import problem in spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, crud, notnull

I'm trying to do a CRUD with spring using the h2 database and lombok, and it's giving me an error like this:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null

My controller:

```
package br.edu.unicesumar.crud.controller;

import br.edu.unicesumar.crud.model.domain.Pessoa;
import br.edu.unicesumar.crud.model.repository.PessoaRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pessoa")
public class PessoaController {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Pessoa> all() {
        return pessoaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Pessoa getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return pessoaRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Pessoa create(@RequestBody Pessoa nova) {
        return pessoaRepository.save(nova);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        pessoaRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

My Entity service:

```
package br.edu.unicesumar.crud.model.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ES_PESSOA")  // para tabelas com nome diferente da entidade
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "doc", length = 14) // se necessário, informar atribuições para a coluna
    private String documento;


    public Pessoa(Long id, String nome, String documento) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    // getters e setters necessários para serializar e deserializar a classe para json

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }

    public void setDocumento(String documento) {
        this.documento = documento;
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
package br.edu.unicesumar.crud.model.repository;

import br.edu.unicesumar.crud.model.domain.Pessoa;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PessoaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoa, Long> {
}
```

I would like to understand why @notnull validation is being required and applied even without it being included in the code.

Comment: Which endpoint and with what values are you calling?
Where is Lombok here?

Comment: where you added @NotNull ??

Comment: Where is this exception thrown? For both `JpaRespository.findById()` and `JpaRepository.deleteById()` the id **must not** be null or they will throw an "IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null" but I can't see a path in your code where you would call either of these methods with a null argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in Java, however, I believe it could be something related to pom.xml
Follow my pom to stop giving this error:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.edu.unicesumar</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crud</name>
    <description>Crud com MVC</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).